# How to make .NET Setup Project install program to something other than Microsoft

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

How do I make .NET Setup Project install program to something other than Microsoft? I've tried modifying the Assembly Information, but that didn't do it. Is there a settings file of some kind that will force the setup project to install to a folder that I specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the deployment project in VS. Choose View → Editor → File System → Application Folder. Choose Properties. The DefaultLocation property is where the app gets installed by default.

Desktop apps should be installed to the user's Program Files folder, there is a Windows Installer [property value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) [ProgramFilesFolder] for this.